# Unity C# - How to find point C in a right-angled triangle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, trigonometry, unity3d-editor

could you please help me with this task? Here's the problem:

We know the locations of point A and point B, and we know that our triangle is right-angled. We also know that the right angle will be at point C, and we understand that the sum of all angles in a right-angled triangle equals 180 degrees.

The question is, how do we find the location of point C?

I'm developing a goalkeeper bot, where point A represents the goalkeeper, B represents the ball, and point C is the location where the bot should reach to stand opposite the ball. The goalkeeper always has their back turned to the goal, so we can use transform.right.

All points are Vector3, where Y will always be 0.

(In the picture, there is a top-down projection. The goal and the goalkeeper can rotate, but the goalkeeper will always have their back to the goal.)

[image]

I've tried many ways to solve this problem, but haven't been able to arrive at the correct solution.

Comment: If you know the direction of C relative to A then you can obtain C by projecting AB onto said direction vector. Otherwise, C can be any point on the circumcircle of AB.

Comment: Only knowing point A and B is not enough information ... You need at least one of the angles ... but if you already know the direction of the pink box you can use [`Vector3.Project`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html)

Comment: In general note that this behaviour would be rather bad for a keeper ;) You want to stand in a position where you can potentially cover both short and long edge of the goal ;)

Comment: See [Vector Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection). I would highly recommend reading up a bit on linear algebra. There seem to be some books/resources specifically designed for games and/or graphics.

Comment: I know all angles too, C - 90, A - I calculate with Vector3.Angle betwen BA and BC (BC is goalkeeper transform.right * someLength), so I calculate andgle B = 180 - C - A, but how I can draw from point B with calculated angle?

Comment: Shouldn't the goal be horizontal?  The goal appears to be in a line from A to C which is at an angle.  The problem is simpler if the goal is on the x axis (horizontal).

Comment: @jdweng if we know the goal's rotation (which seems the case) it doesn't really matter

Comment: @derHugo : We do not know the goal's rotation.  Only the angle A to B.  It is simpler to solve issue if goal is horizontal.

Comment: @jdweng we do know the goal ... A to B has no angle it's a single vector ... of course things are always easier if they are axis aligned ... in this case we know the axis though so it's no problem at all ;)

Comment: @derHugo : A vector always has an angle.  The angle is the arcTan(y2-y1/x2-x1)

Comment: @jdweng angle against what? yes against the world axis ... but this info alone would be worth nothing in the open 2D/3D space if as OP states the goal can be rotated ... as said of course everything is always easier if you have axis aligned stuff ... but well .. what if not? ^^ Btw even for wold space projction I would still simply use `Vector3.Project` with `Vector3.right` instead of doing my own calculations ;)

Comment: @derHugo : And everything is always easier when you have a library method to do the work.

Comment: @jdweng exactly ;) Don't re-invent the wheel ... [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/ddda763e79614c13cb63ec8b9dac375fd3be2b24/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L292) is available btw if you still want to know how it works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you know the `goal` rotation / direction and lets just say we can directly use the goal's `right` vector as a normal then you could simply use [`Vector3.Project`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html)

```
Vector3 A, B;
Transform Goal;

// Vector A->B
// mapped onto the Goal.right direction
// and result applied as new vector relative to A
Vector3 C = A + Vector3.Project(B - A, Goal.right);
```

No need to calculate the angles yourself ;)

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much! Awesomness solution, works perfect <3